# Why is the part of a sphere's area directly proportional to the square of its radius?

Tags: electric-fields, dimensional-analysis, geometry

Solid angle in the book is explained in this way:

> "...Let $dA$ be a small area element of the surface of the sphere. If the points situated on the boundary of this area be joined to $O$ (the center of the sphere), then the lines so drawn will subtend a solid angle $dw$ at $O$. Since the spherical area $dA$ is directly proportional to the square of the radius ($r^2$), the ratio $\frac{dA}{r^2}$ is a constant. This ratio is called the solid angle $dw$ subtended by the area $dA$ at the center."

The sphere's area is $4πr^2$. is that why it's said that $dA$ is directly proportional to $r^2$? also is it just for definition's sake that $dw$ is the ratio? or is there any underlying concept to grasp?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be a more mathematical question.
if you know how an angle in the plain is defined ist is the length of the part of the circle  delimitated by the angle divided by the radius, so $d\phi=\frac{ds}{r}$, The same applies to the "3-dimensional" angel, you define it as the area of the surface of a sphere  , deliminated by this angle, wich you best visualize as a cone from the middle of the sphere cutting out a part area  of the sphere , like the two lines cutting out a 2d angel in a circle.
And yes, you have to divide bei r^2 since the area increases with r^2-

Comment: It was quite mathematical but I stumbled upon it in my physics book so just went ahead with this site. thanks for the explanation it helped.